# How can I access tag's value inside id with beautifulsoap in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I 'm trying to pull data from website with beautifulsoap in python but the data confused me a bit and I don't quite understand how to do it. What I want to do is actually pull certain data. I just want to capture the **title**, **examples** ,**meaning** and **origin** data in the page, how can I do that?

**I will share my own code but this is not correct code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.englishclub.com/ref/Idioms/"


mylist = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H",
    "I",
    "J",
    "K",
    "L",
    "M",
    "N",
    "O",
    "P",
    "Q",
    "R",
    "S",
    "T",
    "U",
    "V",
    "W"
]

list = {}
idiomsUrls=[]


for i in range(23):

    list[mylist[i]] = []
    result = requests.get(url+mylist[i]+"/", headers = headers)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    idiomsUrls = doc.select('.linktitle a')

    for tag in idiomsUrls:
        result = requests.get(tag['href'])
        doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text,"html.parser")
        idioms = doc.select('main')
        

with open('idioms.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(list, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

**I shared the screenshot of the data I want to capture.**

[image]

The data I want to capture here is the idiom title in the `h1` tag, **as an example**, here is the `above board`, then **the meaning** and example section below it. examples There is also a part called origin at the bottom of the `ul` and `li` tags, I couldn't find how to shoot these parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep it simple and select your elements more specific by `tag`, `id` or `class` and try to avoid using reserved [`keywords`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) as variable names:

```
data = []

for i in mylist:
    result = requests.get(url+i+"/", headers = headers)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text)

    for tag in doc.select('.linktitle a'):
        result = requests.get(tag['href'])
        doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text)
        data.append({
            'idiom': doc.h1.get_text(strip=True),
            'meaning': doc.select_one('h1 ~ h2 + p').get_text(strip=True),
            'examples':[e.get_text(strip=True) for e in doc.select('main ul li')]
        })
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.englishclub.com/ref/Idioms/"


mylist = ["A"] #...

data = []

for i in mylist:

    result = requests.get(url+i+"/", headers = headers)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text)

    for tag in doc.select('.linktitle a'):
        result = requests.get(tag['href'])
        doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text)
        data.append({
            'idiom': doc.h1.get_text(strip=True),
            'meaning': doc.select_one('h1 ~ h2 + p').get_text(strip=True),
            'examples':[e.get_text(strip=True) for e in doc.select('main ul li')]
        })

data
```

##### Output

```
[{'idiom': 'above board',
  'meaning': "If something is above board, it's been done in a legal and honest way.",
  'examples': ["I'm sure the deal was completely above board as I know James well and he'd never do anything illegal or corrupt.",
   'The minister claimed all the appointments were above board and denied claims that some positions had been given to his friends.']},
 {'idiom': 'above the law',
  'meaning': 'If someone is above the law, they are not subject to the laws of a society.',
  'examples': ["Just because his father is a rich and powerful man, he seems to think he's above the law and he can do whatever he likes.",
   'In a democracy, no-one is above the law - not even a president or a prime-minister.']},
 {'idiom': "Achilles' heel",
  'meaning': "An Achilles' heel is a weakness that could result in failure.",
  'examples': ["He's a good golfer, but his Achilles' heel is his putting and it's often made him lose matches.",
   "The country's dependence on imported oil could prove to be its Achilles' heel if prices keep on rising."]},...]
```

Comment: How can I add letters to the beginning of the list, for example, I want to have another list that starts with the letter A, and the ones that start with the letter B, so that I can access the data more easily. By the way your code works fine

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - Just to point, you could also filter your list by e.g. `[i for i in data if i['idiom'].startswith('b')]`